# Асинхронность в Redis

Tags: php, redis

Здравствуйте.

Хочу организовать очередь с использованием Redis.

Вопрос: есть ли возможность организовать асинхронную работу Redis?

Пример:  
Пользователь создает запись, я беру эту запись, записываю ее в List с помощью lpush. Затем пользователь может идти дальше бороздить просторы сайта, а в этот момент запустится метод для обработки очереди, который сохранит данные на стороннем сервере. Т.е. проблема в том, что мне надо ждать, пока Redis сохранит данные, а мне хотелось бы это делать фоново.

Comment: Ну так запустите демона на очередь, пускай он её слушает постоянно, и при появлении нового сообщения будет его обрабатывать. А пользователь сам себе пускай гуляет.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду сделать крон, который будет чекать каждые минут 5, например?

Comment: нет, я имею ввиду фоновый процесс, который будет работать постоянно. 

Самое простое, что можно придумать:

file service.php :

    <?php 
    //тут подключение к редису и все настройки
    while(true){
     // тут делаем lpop();
    }?>

ну и запускаем из консоли 

    $ php service.php

Comment: Вариант, но хотелось, конечно, красивее сделать))

Comment: Куда уж красивее? Если хотите сделать вообще круто, то устанавливайте RabbitMQ, настраивайте обменники и очереди, вешайте подисчиков, опять же, как демонов. Крон не тру в данном случае.